# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'human'

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске сервера ошибка:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'human'

Содержание файла views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello from Human!</h1>")
```

Содержание файла Newsproject.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('newsproject.urls')),
    path('', include('human.urls')),
]
```

Содержание файла settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for Newsproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-r)ca3ow2@d7edrm_*^fmuz4vbr)7k(nwl9$7d!%+7#n83_0n!k'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'human',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Newsproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Newsproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Содержание файла human.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', hello, name='hello'),
]
```

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать обра приложения и дать им названия в НИЖНЕМ регистре.

Comment: Как запускаете сервер?

Comment: python manage.py runserver

Comment: В коде `human`, а на скриншоте папка `Human` — определитесь с регистром

Comment: А подключением newsprojects.urls внутри newsprojects.urls вы рискуете вызвать бесконечную рекурсию

Comment: Поправил "А подключением newsprojects.urls внутри newsprojects.urls вы рискуете вызвать бесконечную рекурсию". Но теперь пишет Using the URLconf defined in newsproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

human/
The empty path didn’t match any of these. Страница не найдена 404

Comment: Если вы хотите добавить приложение в установленные приложения, то в `INSTALLED_APPS` надо добавить строку вида `<ИМЯ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ>.apps.****Config`

Comment: У меня там сейчас так INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'human',
]